# polynomial contrasts mixed model with repeated measures

Tags: r, repeated-measures

I'm trying to compute a mixed design with an multilevel approach in R. I'm quite new to the game and really hope someone can help me here.

What I have is a group of people measured 10 times (in 10 weeks) concerning their adherence to a specific treatment.
The hypothesis is that adherence reduces over time in a linear manner.

The persons are from different age and they have a baseline burden (burden in first month of treatment), which are variables I want to include based on previous findings, but there is no concrete hypothesis on their influence.

My data is not balanced and does not fullfill sphericity assumptions therefore I'm trying to use a the lme approach.

age and burden are numerical variables

I'm mainly using Andy Field to do this. This is what I have "created"

```
baseline <- lme(adherence~1, random = ~1|id/week, data=data, method= 'ML')
weekM <- update(baseline, .~. + week)
ageM <- update(weekM, .~. + age)
burdenM <- update(ageM, .~. + burden)
week_ageM <- update(burdenM, .~. + week:age)
week_burdenM <- update(week_ageM, .~. + week:burden)
burden_ageM <- update(week_burdenM, .~. + burden:age)
burden_age_weekM <- update(burden_ageM, .~. + burden:age:week)

anova(baseline, weekM, ageM, burdenM, week_ageM, week_burdenM, burden_ageM, burden_age_weekM)
```

What i wanted to do before I found out my assumption is not met and the data is not balanced, was:

```
library(emmeans)

emmeans_for_contrast <- emmeans(model_made_with_aov, ~ week)
emmeans_for_contrast 

lin_cont <- c(-0.4599331, -0.3763089, -0.2926847, -0.2090605, -0.1254363,-0.0418121, 0.0418121  ,0.1254363 ,0.2090605,0.2926847,0.3763089,0.4599331)
qua_cont <- c(0.501828160, 0.228103709, 0.009124148, -0.155110522, -0.264600302,-0.319345193, -0.319345193 ,-0.264600302, -0.155110522, 0.009124148, 0.228103709, 0.501828160)

contrast(emmeans_for_contrast, list(lin_cont, qua_cont), adjust = 'bonferroni')
```

I know that emmeans work for lme as well, but I am not sure which model to include here ? Do I use compute a new one with all the variables that made a significant difference or do I use the one that includes all?

I hope this is enough information. Please let me know what else might be needed.
Below is my dataframe.

```
head(stack_preview, n =8)
# A tibble: 8 × 5
                  id      age                    burden   week           adherence
               <int>    <dbl>                     <dbl> <fct>              <dbl>
1                 27       37                         5 week  0            0    
2                 99       43                         0 week  0            0
3                104       24                         9 week  0            0    
4                132       28                        12 week  0            0.143
5                161       27                         9 week  0            0.429
6                179       57                        16 week  0     0.714
7                254       52                         7 week  0     0.143
8                331       48                         7 week 0     0.571
```

Feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by Andy Field? (auto-incorrect?) What is model_made_with_aov, and why use that instead of one of the lme models? And note that method="ML" is good for comparing models with anova, but suggest re-fitting with REML before getting means and contrasts. Finally, contrast(emmresult, "poly") is available for testing polynomial contrasts.

Comment: With andy field I mean the author (discovering statistics using R). I thought that what I was doing is comparing them. This is what was proposed within the statistics book: adding one predictor with each model and then see which predictors actually improve the fit. Ok this means when I am using the emmresult (poly) I can leave the default contrast setting as it is and afterwards compute those? Thanks!

Comment: You can leave week as a factor. It does not matter what contrasts attribute you use as far as emmeans is concerned.